# Where did they go / do they went?

Tags: past-tense

> Where did they go?
>   Where do they went?

Can you please advise which of above forms is correct?  I'm pretty sure that first one is fine but wondering about second one.

Can I use a second form as well or it's incorrect?

Comment: No, your second version is completely ungrammatical.

Comment: After do/does/did you need the bare infinitive. "do" + went (past form)  never go together.

Comment: "Go" and "do" are some of the trickier verbs in English, so I can understand why you might have doubts about this. @rogermue - You could leave that as an answer.

Comment: Also, just as a note, "or it's incorrect?" should be "or is it incorrect?" _It is_ is a statement. _Is it_ is a question.

Answer (score 3):

After do/does/did you need the bare infinitive, and of course after don't/does'nt/didn't. Do/does/did and a past form, such as went, never go together.