# "Where do you lived?" or "Where did you live?"

Tags: spoken-english, indian-english

Which is the correct question?

Similarly,

> "When did you move to New York?" or "When do you moved to New York?".

Please tell me the reason behind each question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where did they go / do they went?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59166/where-did-they-go-do-they-went)

Answer (score 1):

**Some** question forms in English:

**Present Tense**

**Do you move** your car everyday? Where **do you live**?

Interrogative: do/does, the subject and the verb.

**Past Tense (Simple Past)**

**Did you move** your car yesterday? Where **did you live in New York**?

Interrogative: **did subject verb**

- When **did you move** to NY? [simple past tense]
- When **do you move** to NY? [meaning: when are you going to move to NY]

**The ed form is only for regular verbs in the declarative form:**

- He moved to NY last week. [declarative]
- Did he move to NY last week? [interrogative]

Answer (score 0):

"Where did you live?" or "Where do you live?" are correct because, if the helping verb is the second form of the verb, it should be followed by the infinitive or the first form of the verb.

For example, we say, "When did you move to New York? or "Did you move to New York?"

Even if the question is in the present,the main verb should be in the first form of the verb, so "When do you moved to New York?" is wrong.

The rule applies to almost all helping verbs; for example:

- When did you come?
- When do you come?
- When will you come?
- When can you come?
- Why should you come?

In all those examples we can not replace *come* with *came*.